# Problems with fillbetween library and global settings

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

It seems, that the global axis options are not passed through when using the fillbetween library. Can anybody confirm that?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\small},every tick/.append style={very thin,black},
             every axis/.append style={very thin,black},
             }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
\nextgroupplot
     \addplot [blue] {rnd};
\nextgroupplot
%\nextgroupplot[every tick/.append style={very thin,black},
%              every axis/.append style={very thin,black}]
     \addplot [red] {rnd};      
     \addplot[draw=none,
              name path=A,
             ] {rnd}; 
     \addplot [draw=none,domain=-6:6,name path=B] {0}; % “fictional” curve
     \addplot [gray,opacity=0.5] fill between[of=A and B,domain=-6:6]; % filling                    

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see your problem. Can you add an screenshot with the problem?

Comment: This is most probably because of an already reported bug; see https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/138/.